# Json body integer validation using spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

my request body looks like this

```
{
  "id": 23,
  "no": 23,
  "Code": 99,
  "badgeNumber": 5,
  "empid": "mm108",
  "name": "sam",
}
```

my integer fields(id,no,code) are optional but it should throw an error when a empty string is passed, which is not, how would i validate it.

i cannot use @NotNull because it is an optional it can be null but should not accept empty string or string with spaces.

Comment: add your request body class in your question

Comment: put your code to help us to understand you case

Answer (score 2):

If you use **Integer** instead of **int** in your request body there will be handle **null** and **empty** string. If you want to handle **spaces** or **any character** then need to use custom desereilzer like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class IntegerDeserialization extends JsonDeserializer<Integer> {
@Override
public Integer deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    try{
        return p.readValuesAs(Integer.class).next();
    }catch (Exception ex){
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

and your req body like :

```
public class TestReq implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@JsonDeserialize(using = IntegerDeserialization.class)
private Integer id;
@JsonDeserialize(using = IntegerDeserialization.class)
private Integer no;
@JsonDeserialize(using = IntegerDeserialization.class)
private Integer code;

//getter setter
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`StringUtils.isBlank("yourString")` should do the trick for that.